# Postgresql Autodoc install: "No rule to make target `postgresql_autodoc.1.in', needed by `postgresql_autodoc.1'. Stop

Tags: postgresql, makefile, autodoc

I downloaded the latest Postgresql Autodoc (v1.41) from http://www.rbt.ca/autodoc/index.html
When I run make I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `postgresql_autodoc.1.in', needed by `postgresql_autodoc.1'.  Stop.
```

What is the problem?

Mac OS X Lion, 10.7.5
GNU Make 3.81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's broken.  Please write to the author to get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks Peter!  Per your suggestion, I just sent author Rod Taylor an email.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you can circumvent the problem pretty easily:

```
tar -zxf postgresql_autodoc-1.41.tar.gz
cd postgresql_autodoc
cp postgresql_autodoc.1 postgresql_autodoc.1.in
make
```